# Phonegap Media API trying to access audio locally

Tags: android, audio, cordova

I am currently working on an app that has to play audio from an external source. It is in the .amr file format, but giving it the URL and looking at log cat I can see its trying to access it locally logging:

```
FAILED renaming /storage/sdcard0/tmprecording.3gp to /storage/sdcard0/http://URL/audio.amr
```

Here is my player code

```
    function play(source) { 
var media = new Media(source, Played, Failed); 
media.play(); 
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "playing"; 
}
```

with the function linked to a button and given a URL to the audio. I am testing this out on Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it was just an issue with formats, .amr is an incompatible format so it didnt work